# Recommnedation for books and material for solving differerntial equations through neural networks

Tags: neural-networks, references, differential-equations, neural-odes

I was going through some past and recent papers on using neural networks for solving ordinary and partial differential equations.  One of the fascinating papers that inspired a flurry of papers is
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.10561.pdf.

I was looking for some nice books/tutorials about " Differential equations and Neural networks " if there are any. I would be extremely grateful for any recommendations in this regard.

Comment: It's a very young and small area, so your best written sources are going to be the paper itself and those that cite it.

Comment: Whenever I want to get started researching a new technical topic, I start with Google Scholar and ArXiv Sanity.